# Revit Sketched Stair Using Python: Only works at Level One

Tags: python, python-2.7, revit-api

I am working on a Dynamo graph that uses a Python node to create stairs with landing by importing CAD geometry.  You can see graphs and other info at the Dynamo Forum post [here](https://forum.dynamobim.com/t/problem-creating-second-level-of-stairs-via-python-dynamo/60336)

It works fine when set to Base Level 1 (to Level 2), but any higher and it is created one full level above where it should and giving an error:    [Warning1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MACH4.png) [Warning2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhD1H.png)

Any lower (B1 to Level 1) and it gives an error as well as not creating the stairs.[PythonScriptError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4Bvm.png)

No luck tweaking Revit and Dynamo settings, CAD file or placing the CAD import on different levels.  The Python script is the only thing left:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *

clr.AddReference('RevitServices')
import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
from RevitServices.Transactions import TransactionManager
doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument

clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
import Autodesk
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *
from Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture import StairsRun
from Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture import StairsLanding
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import CurveLoop

clr.AddReference('RevitNodes')
import Revit
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.GeometryConversion)
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.Elements)

doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument    
class StairsFailurePreprocessor( IFailuresPreprocessor ):
    def PreprocessFailures(self, failuresAccessor):
        return FailureProcessingResult.Continue

baseLevel = UnwrapElement(IN[0])
nextLevel = UnwrapElement(IN[1])
b1Curves = IN[2]
r1Curves = IN[3]
p1Curves = IN[4]
b2Curves = IN[5]
r2Curves = IN[6]
p2Curves = IN[7]
elCurves = IN[8]

TransactionManager.Instance.ForceCloseTransaction()

newStairsScope = StairsEditScope(doc, 'New Stairs')
newStairsId = newStairsScope.Start(baseLevel.Id, nextLevel.Id)

trans = Transaction(doc, 'Add Runs and Landings to Stairs')
trans.Start()

bdryCurves1 = list(b1Curves)
riserCurves1 = list(r1Curves)
pathCurves1 = list(p1Curves)

bdryCurves2 = list(b2Curves)
riserCurves2 = list(r2Curves)
pathCurves2 = list(p2Curves)

landingLoop = CurveLoop.Create(elCurves)

r1Count = len(r1Curves)
r2Count = len(r2Curves)

newRun1 = Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.StairsRun.CreateSketchedRun(doc, newStairsId, baseLevel.Elevation, bdryCurves1, riserCurves1, pathCurves1)
newLanding = Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.StairsLanding.CreateSketchedLanding(doc, newStairsId, landingLoop, newRun1.TopElevation)
newRun2 = Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.StairsRun.CreateSketchedRun(doc, newStairsId, newLanding.BaseElevation, bdryCurves2, riserCurves2, pathCurves2)
trans.Commit()
newStairsScope.Commit(StairsFailurePreprocessor())

OUT = newStairsId
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
LoRue

Answer (score -1):

Elevation is 0. else is wil be elevation + elevation!

"newRun1 = StairsRun.CreateSketchedRun(doc, newStairsId , **0** , bdryCurves, riserCurves, pathCurves )"

```
import clr #.NET Laden
import sys #sys is de fundamentele Python bibliotheek
#the standard IronPython libraries
sys.path.append('C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib') #Imports the
#standard IronPython libraries, which cover everything from servers and
#encryption through to regular expressions.
import System #The System namespace at the root of .NET
from System import Array #.NET class for handling array information
import System.Collections.Generic as MGen #Module kan nu benaderd worden met MGen.xxxx
#from System.Collections.Generic import * #Lets you handle generics. Revit's API
#sometimes wants hard-typed 'generic' lists, called ILists. If you don't need
#these you can delete this line.
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')  #A Dynamo library for its proxy geometry
#classes. You'll only need this if you're interacting with geometry.
import Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry as AGeo #Module kan worden opgeroepen a=met AGeo.xxxx
#from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import * #Loads everything in Dynamo's
#geometry library
clr.AddReference("RevitNodes") #Dynamo's nodes for Revit
import Revit #Loads in the Revit namespace in RevitNodes
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.Elements) #More loading of Dynamo's Revit libraries
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.GeometryConversion) #More loading of Dynamo's
#Revit libraries. You'll only need this if you're interacting with geometry.
clr.AddReference("RevitServices") #Dynamo's classes for handling Revit documents
import RevitServices 
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager #An internal Dynamo class
#that keeps track of the document that Dynamo is currently attached to
from RevitServices.Transactions import TransactionManager #A Dynamo class for
#opening and closing transactions to change the Revit document's database

clr.AddReference("RevitAPI") #Adding reference to Revit's API DLLs
clr.AddReference("RevitAPIUI") #Adding reference to Revit's API DLLs

import Autodesk #Loads the Autodesk namespace
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *
from Autodesk.Revit.UI import *
from Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture import *

doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument #Dit is het actieve Revit document
uiapp = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentUIApplication #Setting a handle to the active Revit UI document
app = uiapp.Application  #Setting a handle to the currently-open instance of the Revit application
uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument #Setting a handle to the currently-open instance of the Revit UI application
# Hieronder kan je dan gaan programmeren
#Gebruik boiler template
class StairsFailurePreprocessor( IFailuresPreprocessor ):
    def PreprocessFailures(self, failuresAccessor):
        return FailureProcessingResult.Continue
        
BL=UnwrapElement(IN[0])
TL=UnwrapElement(IN[1])
newStairsScope = StairsEditScope(doc, "New Stairs")

newStairsId = newStairsScope.Start( BL.Id, TL.Id)
trans = Autodesk.Revit.DB.Transaction(doc, "Trap maken")
trans.Start()

Traplengte=UnitUtils.Convert(3300, DisplayUnitType.DUT_MILLIMETERS, DisplayUnitType.DUT_DECIMAL_FEET)
Hoogte=BL.Elevation
#Lijnen maken voor een geschetste trap
bdryCurves=MGen.List[Curve]() #cl is een revittype lijst voor curves
pnt1 = XYZ(0, 0, Hoogte)
pnt2 = XYZ(Traplengte, 0, Hoogte)
pnt3 = XYZ(0, 6, Hoogte)
pnt4 = XYZ(Traplengte, 6, Hoogte)

#boundaries       
bdryCurves.Add(Line.CreateBound(pnt1, pnt2))
bdryCurves.Add(Line.CreateBound(pnt3, pnt4))

riserCurves=MGen.List[Curve]() #cl is een revittype lijst voor curves
#riser curves
Aantrede=Traplengte / 15
for NX in range(16):
    end0 = XYZ(pnt1.X + (NX * Aantrede), 0, Hoogte)
    end1 = XYZ(pnt3.X + (NX * Aantrede), 6, Hoogte)
    riserCurves.Add(Line.CreateBound(end0, end1))
    
pathCurves=MGen.List[Curve]() #cl is een revittype lijst voor curves
#stairs path curves
pathEnd0 = XYZ(0,3,Hoogte)
pathEnd1 = XYZ(Traplengte,3,Hoogte)
pathCurves.Add(Line.CreateBound(pathEnd0, pathEnd1))


newRun1 = StairsRun.CreateSketchedRun(doc, newStairsId , 0 , bdryCurves, riserCurves, pathCurves )

#locationLine = Line.CreateBound(XYZ(20, -5, newRun1.TopElevation), XYZ(35, -5, newRun1.TopElevation))

#newRun2 = StairsRun.CreateStraightRun(doc, newStairsId, locationLine, StairsRunJustification.Center)
#newRun2.ActualRunWidth = 10

'''
#Add a landing between the runs
landingLoop = CurveLoop()
p1 = XYZ(15, 10, 0)
p2 = XYZ(20, 10, 0)
p3 = XYZ(20, -10, 0)
p4 = XYZ(15, -10, 0)
curve_1 = Line.CreateBound(p1, p2)
curve_2 = Line.CreateBound(p2, p3)
curve_3 = Line.CreateBound(p3, p4)
curve_4 = Line.CreateBound(p4, p1)
landingLoop.Append(curve_1)
landingLoop.Append(curve_2)
landingLoop.Append(curve_3)
landingLoop.Append(curve_4)
newLanding = StairsLanding.CreateSketchedLanding(doc, newStairsId, landingLoop, newRun1.TopElevation)
'''

trans.Commit()
trans.Dispose()


newStairsScope.Commit(StairsFailurePreprocessor())
newStairsScope.Dispose()
ele=doc.GetElement(newStairsId)
OUT=newStairsId, ele
```

Comment: It worked!  I think I understand:  The Elevation attribute of baselevel.Elevation _adds_ to the baselevel instead of only returning the height of the provided level.  Will look again at the Revit API documentation.  So tricky, yet so simple!  Was about to give up or escalate it.  Many thanks!